# Projecting a targetting ring using direct3d

Tags: math, 3d, directx, direct3d

I'm trying to draw a "targetting ring" on the ground below a "unit" in a hobby 3d game I'm working on. Basically I want to project a bright red patterned ring onto the ground terrain below the unit.

The only approach I can think of is this -

1. Draw the world once as normal
2. Draw
   the world a second time but in my
   vertex shader I have the world x,y,z
   coordinates of the vertex and I can
   pass in the coordinates of the
   highlighted unit - so I can
   calculate what the u,v coordinates
   in my project texture should be at
   that point in the world for that
   vertex.

   I'd then use the pixel shader to pick pixels from the target ring texture and blend them into the previously drawn world.

I believe that should be easy, and should work but it involves me drawing the whole visible world twice as it's hard to determine exactly which polygons the targetting ring might fall onto. It seems a big overhead to draw the whole world twice, once for the normal lit textured ground, and then again just to draw the targetting ring.

Is there a better approach that I'm missing?

Comment: Isn't it the point of pixel shaders to allow this kind of calculation on the first pass?

Comment: I guess I can combine the two into a single pixel shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Projective Texture Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_texture_mapping) is your friend.

Comment: Thanks. Is that how projective texture mapping works though - take the x, y, z position of the pixel, and try to work out which texture pixel is mapped to it?

Comment: @JohnB: It works by setting position and angle of the projection and then just projecting the texture on any object that is in the way of the projection.  Obviously if you draw the objects with the projective texture on them they also get the texture projected on them but if you only want it on terrain then only run the projected texture on the terrain.  Its effective and very easy to set up.